# Extbase: get/save specific language of object

Tags: typo3, extbase

In a CommandController, I need to sync objects with an external source. The source is multi-language and shall be mapped to localized records in Typo3.

I just seem too blind to find options to ...

a) get records in a specific language

b) add/update records in a specific language
... (from a CommandController context).

I was expecting this to be a function of the model (AbstractEntity) or maybe the repository, but could not find any public lang/sys_lang/localize-functions there.

(Typo3 version 6.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method in your repository class to get all records with the sys_language_uid  you need and use that method to get all the records.

If you model does not have the sys_language_uid, add it so you can use it in your controller.
(if your model has sys_laguage_uid, you can use $yourrepo->findBySysLanguageUid(1)  )

Probably you need to change the defaultQuerySettings so you can retrieve the any language, regarding the site language (if you are using a FE ext)

adding the records with a specific language is $yourobject->setSysLangUid(1); (or whatever lang id)

Comment: Thank you.
I added it to the model and was able to retrieve records by:
`        $q = $this->propertyRepository->createQuery();
        $q->getQuerySettings()->setRespectSysLanguage(FALSE);
        $q->matching(
                $q->logicalAnd(
                        $q->equals('sysLanguageUid', $sysLangUid),
                        ... (other constraints)
                )
        );
`
but to SET the language I actually needed to do          `$object->_setProperty('_languageUid', $sysLangUid);`